# Is it the best to implement ObservableBase in this situation or is there another way?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

First of all, I didn't find a good example of custom implementation of the ObservableBase or AnonymousObservable. I have no idea which one I need to implement in my case if any. The situation is this.

I use a third-party library and there is a class let's call it Producer which allows me to set a delegate on it like objProducer.Attach(MyHandler). MyHandler will receive messages from the Producer. I'm trying to create a wrapper around the Producer to make it observable and ideally to be it a distinct type instead of creating just an instance of observable (like Observable.Create).

EDITED: Third-party Producer has the following interface

```
public delegate void ProducerMessageHandler(Message objMessage);
public class Producer : IDisposable {
   public void Start();
   public void Attach(ProducerMessageHandler fnHandler);
   public void Dispose();
}
```

as I mentioned I have no control over the source code of it. It is intended to be used like this: create an instance, call Attach and pass a delegate, call Start which basically initiates receiving messages inside the provided delegated when Producer receives them or generates them.

I was thinking about creating public `class ProducerObservable : ObservableBase<Message>` so that when somebody subscribes to it I would (Rx library would) push messages to the observers. It seems that I need to call Attach somewhere in the constructor of my ProducerObservable, then I need somehow to call OnNext on the observers attached to it. Does it mean that I have to code all this: add a list of observers `LinkedList<IObserver<Message>>` to the class and then add observers when SubscribeCore abstract method is called on the ProducerObservable? Then apparently I would be able to enumerate the `LinkedList<IObserver<Message>>` in the MyHandler and call OnNext for each one. All these looks feasible but it doesn't feel exactly right. I would expect .net reactive extensions to be better prepare to situations like this and have at least the implementation of the `LinkedList<IObserver<Message>>` ready somewhere in base class.

Comment: Here's a good rule to live by when using Rx: If ever you're implementing `IObservable<T>` or `IObserver<T>` then you should stop - you **are** doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do. C#'s event/delegate model is an implementation of the Observer pattern. Yet you seem to want to wrap another observer pattern on top of this.

Comment: @DavidArno - Are you familiar with the Rx library?

Comment: I have to agree with @Enigmativity, creating your own `IObservable` implementation should be extremely rare. If you have a regular event exposed, [`Observable.FromEventPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) should be enough here...

Comment: @Enigmativity, clearly not! I missed the Rx reference due to skimming. I'll leave this question to those that know what they are talking about therefore! :)

Comment: @DavidArno - In basic terms, Rx raises events to first-class object status and allows LINQ queries to be performed on events. It is far far far more powerful than the standard event/delegate model.

Comment: @alex.49.98 - Can you please edit your question and post the signature for `Producer`?

Comment: Apparently I'm asking this question because I'm not proficient with Rx library but I perfectly understand the concept and familiar with many classes and methods. Producer class is not IObservable and I'm trying to make an IObservable wrapper to make it IObservable to use it with other good features of the Rx library like aggregation and then attach Observers to consume the data in unified manner.

Comment: @alex.49.98 - Thanks for posting the signature. Can you let us know if it has any constructors other than the default constructor? Does it implement any interfaces, in particular, `IDisposable`?

Comment: Yes. I forgot about IDisposable. We normally don't call Dispose on it simply because we always need to receive messages from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discussion just gave me an idea. Isn't it just this?

```
public class ProducerObservable : IObservable<Message>, IDisposable {
   private readonly Producer _Producer;
   private readonly Subject<Message> _Subject;

   public ProducerObservable() {
      _Produder = new Producer();
      _Producer.Attach(Message_Received);
      _Subject = new Subject<Message>();
      _Producer.Start();
   }

   public void Dispose() {
      _Producer.Dispose();
      _Subject.Dispose();
   }

   public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Message> objObserver) {
      return _Subject.Subscribe(objObserver);
   }

   private void Message_Received(Message objMessage) {
      _Subject.OnNext(objMessage);
   }
}
```

Thus, it seems to me we avoid extra levels, extra observables, having just a single observable type and basically I see only advantages and no disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

In code that uses Rx, "Producer" objects are usually objects that expose `IObservable<T>` instances via public properties or methods.  It is less common that the `Producer` class itself would implement `IObservable<T>`, and when it does, it does so by using `Rx` to do the heavy lifting under the hood.  You absolutely never want to implement an `IObservable<T>` yourself.

Here's an example where the observable is exposed as a property:

```
public class Producer
{
    public Producer(ThirdPartyLib.Producer p)
    {
        var c = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            ProducerMessageHandler h = msg => observer.OnNext(msg);
            p.Attach(h);
            p.Start();

            return Disposable.Empty;
        }).Publish();

        // Connect the observable the first time someone starts
        // observing
        Stream = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            var subscription = c.Subscribe(observer);
            if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _connected, 1) == 0)
            {
                c.Connect();
            }

            return subscription;
        });
    }

    private int _connected;
    public IObservable<Message> Stream { get; private set; }
}
```

And here is the same example where we actually implement `IObservable<T>` by delegating to Rx:

```
public class Producer : IObservable<Message>
{
    public Producer(ThirdPartyLib.Producer p)
    {
        var c = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            ProducerMessageHandler h = msg => observer.OnNext(msg);
            p.Attach(h);
            p.Start();

            return Disposable.Empty;
        }).Publish();

        // Connect the observable the first time someone starts
        // observing
        _stream = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            var subscription = c.Subscribe(observer);
            if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _connected, 1) == 0)
            {
                c.Connect();
            }

            return subscription;
        });
    }

    private IObservable<Message> _stream;

    // implement IObservable<T> by delegating to Rx
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Message> observer)
    {
        return _stream.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work like this in my situation I guess. There is no Detach method on the Producer (I didn't design it. It is what it is). As I understand you call Attach and then Start for each new observer which is not correct in my case. I need to call Start once as well as Attach and then call OnNext for each subscribed Observer in MyHandler which was attached to the Provider.

Comment: @alex.49.98 once you have it using Rx, there are alot of ways to handle requirements like that.  I modified the example to use `Publish` and start the producer when the first observer arrives--future observers will share the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should be doing to be Rx "friendly":

```
public static class ObservableProducer
{
    public static IObservable<Message> Create()
    {
        return 
            Observable.Using(() => new Producer(), p =>
                Observable.Create<Message>(o => 
                {
                    ProducerMessageHandler handler = m => o.OnNext(m);
                    p.Attach(handler);
                    return Disposable.Create(() => o.OnCompleted());
                }));
    }
}
```

You would use this like this:

```
IObservable<Message> query = ObservableProducer.Create();
```

You should allow multiple `Producer` instances to be created for all new subscriptions - that's how Rx works.

However, if you only want a single `Producer` instance then look at using `.Publish()` on this observable.

Here's how to make sure that the single `Producer` instance is "self-managing":

```
IObservable<Message> query = ObservableProducer.Create().Publish().RefCount();
```

This will create a single `Producer` instance on the first subscription and keep that `Producer` until there are no longer any subscriptions. This makes it "self-managing" and a better solution that rolling your own class.

If you have to implement your own class then you are often going to make mistakes. The class you added as an answer to this question has three that I can see.

1. You instantiate the subject after you attach the message handler. If the producer creates a message during the attach process your code will fail.
2. You don't keep track of the subscriptions. If you don't track your subscriptions then you can't dispose of them. Rx queries can hold open expensive resources so you should dispose of them as early as possible.
3. You don't call `.OnCompleted()` on the subject prior to disposal of the producer.

Here's my implementation of your class:

```
public class ProducerObservable : IObservable<Message>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Producer _Producer;
    private readonly Subject<Message> _Subject;
    private readonly CompositeDisposable _Disposables;

    public ProducerObservable()
    {
        _Subject = new Subject<Message>();
        ProducerMessageHandler fnHandler = m => _Subject.OnNext(m);

        _Producer = new Producer();
        _Producer.Attach(fnHandler);
        _Producer.Start();

        _Disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        _Disposables.Add(_Producer);
        _Disposables.Add(_Subject);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Subject.OnCompleted();
        _Disposables.Dispose();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Message> objObserver)
    {
        var subscription = _Subject.Subscribe(objObserver);
        _Disposables.Add(subscription);
        return subscription;
    }
}
```

I still don't like it. At the time of writing this I'm one of three people with a silver badge in [system.reactive] (no-one has gold yet) and I've never implemented my own observable. I only just realized that I didn't call `.OnCompleted()` on the subject, so I went back and edited my code above. It's a minefield. It's so much better relying on the inbuilt operators.

The reason that `ObservableBase` exists is to help prevent people making mistakes, but it doesn't stop it.

Comment: I guess it should work as expected with .Publish. Still it looks strange, it will add Subject on .Publish call which probably nothing but I'm just curious if that extra layer is necessary and there is no way to avoid it and possibly create an Observable directly from the MyHandler if implementing of IObservable is so forbidden even though there is ObservableBase.

Comment: you shouldn't send out an `OnCompleted` when unsubscribing.  Rx will eat it and not send it to the observer anyway, since it detaches observers once the unsubscribe process begins.

Comment: @alex.49.98 - I've extended my answer in response to your comment and answer.

Comment: Interesting. That brings another question. I was under the assumption that  when you dispose Subject instance all subscribed observers are automatically unsubscribed which is equal to call .Dispose() on each object returned by the .Subscribe. In your example you dispose the Subject and you dispose each object returned by the .Subscribe. Is it really necessary?

Comment: @alex.49.98 - It's just a good habit to get in to. You can dispose subscriptions as often as you like, so no harm, no foul.

Comment: I understand "no harm" part. I'm just trying to put ends together in my mind. If the Subject disposes all subscribed observers it is one story and I'll think about the observables (and subjects in particular) one way. If it doesn't do it it is another story. It helps me to imagine the internals of the library implementation and create better code architecture on top of it.